# Emulating the shell 'echo' function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables, echo, this

I would like to build a function emulating the shell command behaviour: `echo "var: $var"`.
    The scratch of the code could be:

```
// Scratch of a shell like 'echo'
function echo(t){
    var m= t.match(/\$[A-Za-z0-9]+/g);
    m.unique().forEach(function(entry) {
    var re=new RegExp ("\\" + entry, "g");
    t=t.replace(re, this[entry.substr(1)]);
    });
    console.log(t);
}
```

Where `unique()` operates on an array just as the name implies:

```
// Helper function: make array unique
Array.prototype.unique =function () {
    return  this.filter(function(elem, pos) {
        return this.indexOf(elem) == pos;
    }, this);
};
```

When working with global objects everything's fine:

```
//Global objects
var var1="value1";
s="var1 has $var1";    
echo(s);
```

Gives:

```
"var1 has value1"
```

as expected. Unfortunately inside a function:

```
//Global and local objects     
function foo(){
    var var2="value2";
    s2="var2 has $var2";
    echo(s);
    echo(s2);
}

foo();
```

... only the function variable names can be captured:

```
"var1 has value1"
"var2 has undefined"
```

Given that `var1` is stored in `this`, a trivial solution could be storing `var2` there too:

```
function foo(){
    this.var2="value2";
    s2="var2 has $var2";
    echo(s);
    echo(s2);

}
foo();
```

Giving:

```
"var1 has value1"
"var2 has value2"
```

Apart from the cost of rewriting variable declarations, it seems a very bad idea to store everything as a global. Passing to`echo` the array of the single variables involved would transform it in  a `printf` (already implemented). Passing a sequence of `{var1: "value1", ...}` would be more time consuming than `echo` would save.

Do you have any better idea/trick ?

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense? Why would you need to use variables inside strings in a language that doesn't really support it, and without passing the variables to the function there's not much you can do, as the way you're doing it now with `this[entry.substr(1)]`, you're in the global scope, and `this` is the window, and that's why it only works with variables attached to the window.

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo said, this doesn't make much sense.

Instead of trying to force a language to behave like other one does, *you* should adapt to its syntax.

Then, you could use

```
function echo() {
    console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0).join(''));
}
```

And call it like

```
var var1 = "value1";  
echo("var1 has ", var1); // "var1 has value1"
```

Or directly use

```
var var1 = "value1";  
console.log("var1 has " + var1); // "var1 has value1"
```